# List all google storage objects that a Service Account has access to using gcloud or gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, bucket, gsutil

I have been looking into a way to check all the objects (on Google Cloud Storage) that a IAM Service Account has access to. I have tried using several ways, including the Google Cloud Console, I went into my IAM Service Account and tried to query all the resources that this service account have read access, but it is returning empty.

Is there a way to do that using gcloud or gsutil?

---

From my last post, let me try to be more specific. Here are the steps that I took to do it:

1. Went to the IAM --> Service Accounts
2. Create Service Account and set the following: [Service account details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltiXf.png)
3. Didn't set any role to the service account: [Grant this service account access to project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKVGf.png)
4. Didn't set any user access to it: [Grant users access to this service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcqk1.png)
5. Clicked on **DONE**

With that service account in place, I went to one of my Buckets and selected a single file. I've edited a permission on that and added my service account user: [Edit testFile2.txt permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4EkM.png)

Now, I do have a Service Account that have access to a single object as a reader. What I want to know now is, I want to find a way to query ALL THE RESOURCES that this service account has access. So, I could find every single file that it does have access as a reader, for example.

Please let me know if it is much more clear now.

Comment: IIUC there are 2 ways that an account is granted access to GCS objects: first, through the project that owns the bucket (that contains the object); second though the bucket directly. This simplifies the problem because enumerating all objects is expensive. Therefore, I think the solution is to look for policies on a project and all its buckets that bind the account to a `storage.objects.*` or legacy (`owner`, `editor`, `viewer`) role. This is tractable with `gcloud`. Unless others have better solutions or suggestions, I can draft something tomorrow for you.

Comment: Your question does not have a simple answer. There are many ways that a service account can be granted access. Inherited, project, bucket, object. You must check each resource.

Comment: @DazWilkin this is not something that I am thinking of. This solution is more complex than to what I think it will be. I think that there is a way to see all the objects that my Service Account has read access, but I could not find any results on GCP. Something that should be simple, is complex to find a solution.